# AllowHtmlAttribute alternative for .NET Standard since it has been removed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-standard-2.0

I am currently working on a project and encountering an issue since the AllowHtmlAttribute has been removed from .NET Standard. Everywhere I read online says that it's no longer necessary, but it is (or something like it is) for my particular use case. Our models occur in another project, that project is .NET Standard. These models are accessed by both an API project built with .NET Core, and an old webforms project built with .NET Framework.

The problem is the old webforms site throws the old "A potentially dangerous input was detected from the client..." which the AllowHtmlAttribute would resolve, but now that the attribute doesn't exist, I can't apply it. I do not want to turn off input validation. What is the solution here?

Comment: AFAICT `AllowHtmlAttribute` was never part of .NET Standard to begin with; it's specific to ASP.NET MVC, which in turn has never been based on .NET Standard and only supports .NET 4.5. If you need to share models, your best bet is to multi-target you project to both .NET 4.5 and .NET Core (`TargetFrameworks`) and skip .NET Standard altogether (although you could multi-target to .NET 4.5 and Standard, I suppose, but there's little point). You can then exclude `AllowHtmlAttribute` (or more cleanly, define a dummy implementation) through conditional compilation (`#if NET45 ... #else...`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JeroenMostert I've tried this, however I get a project targets 'netstandard2.0;net471'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.1

Comment: A direct reference of the project may not work (I don't know how VS handles this); building it as a NuGet package and referencing that should, though. If that's too much hassle, you may need to experiment a bit -- for example, if the .NET project is using the old-style project format (where it can't be edited unless the project is closed), try upgrading it to new-style and see if that makes references work better. If all else fails building the binaries and referencing those from their net471 map as assemblies directly should work, though you lose out on some IntelliSense.

Comment: The NuGet package isn't something we can do, we need to keep it this way. And while this project is the old-style format, the API is the new-style format, and both give a similar error (only the API being .NET Core instead of Framework).